# How do I disable "rich links" in Messages in Sierra?

Tags: messages, macos

I don't want every link I send through iMessage to be accessed and embedded inline. I can't find a preference setting or defaults key to turn this off.

In this example image, I would want the YouTube link to be sent as a bare link, not a movie + screenshot:
[image: Example]

Comment: Paste without style.

Comment: @Iron I think you're confusing iOS/macOS and rich links in Messages with rich text?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That can't be disabled, it's part of iMessages.

https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT206894

Comment: Everything on that page is also annoying, but I'm specifically targeting rich link expansion, which isn't mentioned.

Comment: It isn't mentioned specifically, true.  Also not mentioned on the Apple sites I visited was how to disable it (apart from turning off iMessages and just using SMS).  I suggest letting Apple know you want this feature: http://www.apple.com/feedback/iphone.html

Comment: I guess that's the best I'll get.

Answer (score 1):

You can add a dot (.) in front of the http before sending it. That should send the link as a link instead of a "rich link"
**.**http://bla.com

Comment: [It doesn't.](https://i.imgur.com/v0kK4XR.png)

Comment: It works if you add text (or a dot) both before **and after** ( . http://bla.com/ . )